# Value of constants when a limit is finite?

Tags: calculus, limits

> If  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{a\cos x+bx\sin x-5}{x^4}$ is finite. Find the value of 'a' and 'b'.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a\left[1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}....\right]+bx\left[x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}....\right]-5}{x^4}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-5+a\left[-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}....\right]+bx\left[x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}....\right]}{x^4}$$

Here we take $a-5=0$ or  $a=5$

And then we proceed further, equating constant terms (terms which do not hold 'x' of any degree) to zero and finding the values.

---

But if we take the case of:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6+x^2-6e^x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}2x-6e^x=-6$$

(using L'Hopital Rule) is a finite limit, but in this case the independent value '6' is not equal to zero. So why do we assume in the above case that the independent values 'a','b' etc. when summed up gives zero?

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Forget rules for a moment. We agree it is obvious that $a=5$. It should also be obvious that we need to eliminate all terms of degree less than 4. So that means taking $-\frac{5}{2}+b=0$ to get rid of the $x^2$ term.

Comment: @almagest surely you're one of a weird guy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your thinking is that the coefficient of limit must not always be zero. Only the coefficient of terms that give undefined limit such as $x^{-k},k>0,k\in\mathbb Z$ must be zero, rest all can be anything.

**"equating constant terms (terms which do not hold 'x' of any degree) to zero"**

is wrong, actually

**"equating constant terms (terms which hold 'x' of degree less than denominator) to zero"**

---

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a\cos x+bx\sin x-5}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a\color{fuchsia}{(1-x^2/2+x^4/24+O(x^6))}+bx\color{blue}{(x-x^3/6+O(x^5))}-5}{x^4}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\color{red}{x^0}(a-5)+\color{red}{x^2}(-a/2+b)+\color{green}{x^4}(a/24-b/6)+\color{green}{O(x^6)}}{x^4}$$
So $a=5$ and $b=a/2=5/2$ since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\color{red}{x^0}}{x^4},\frac{\color{red}{x^2}}{x^4}$ are undefined, so we rid of these terms by making their coefficient zero.

---

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6+x^2-6e^x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{6+x^2-6\color{red}{(1+x+x^2/2+O(x^3))}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-6x+O(x^2)}{x}=-6$$

---

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a+x^2-ae^{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a+x^2-a\color{red}{(1+x+x^2/2+O(x^3))}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-ax+3x^2/2+O(x^3)}{x}=-a$$

Comment: @almagest you're surely going to regret jumping to conclusions without judging properly, see it again.

Comment: @almagest. There is no $x^3$ because of $x\sin(x)$.

Comment: No, I love learning things. I have gracefully retracted the odd comment. That does not mean that your complaints have been justified. The fact is that this answer is unhelpful. He is puzzled, you have not really helped him, as far as I can see.

Comment: Ok, that was wrong, and maybe I should not try to do several things at once. But I leave the downvote to encourage you to be more civil towards those who criticise you, and more helpful to people who ask questions. In response to your comment below the question, most people can seem weird if you get to know them well enough :)  But your comment could easily be interpreted/misinterpreted as pure abuse.

Comment: Alright Aditya you've told me the obvious answer, my question is, for instance if we take the limit $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{a+x^2-ae^x}{x}=-6$ taking a=0 gets us a wrong answer, I am asking about the validity of the constant being 0 in every case.

Comment: @almagest see the edit.

Comment: @HijazAslam edited.

Comment: I saw the edit. I have deleted my incorrect comment.

Comment: This was the answer I had been looking for. Thanks Aditya